# Why do all links change colour when only one is clicked?

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm completely stumped on this one - I have a pretty basic document with an ordered list containing **anchors** and **hidden divs** that show when a link is clicked. The problem is when one link is clicked all links change colour as per the **a:visited css rule**. This does not happen in **IE10** (only the visited link changes colour as expected) but it does happen in **Opera, Chrome and Firefox**.

Here's the markup: http://jsbin.com/usUwecE/3/edit - I'm pretty new to web design so it could be something really obvious, but any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because they all point to the same URL, so when you click on one they all return that they've been visited.

Answer (score 0):

remove hash 
instead of `#javascript:;` use `javascript:;` in your code

Answer (score 0):

As everydayghost said all the href attributes target to #javascript:; which is the same page in address. In order to change this you have to make every href unique ie. href="#div1", href="#div2" ...